# new Random() vs new Random(long seed)

Tags: java

What would be the difference? I appreciate the difference in C++, as not changing the seed will generate the same set of numbers on re-run. However, it doesn't seem to be the case in Java, where the random numbers generated are different in different runs of the program. So, why would anyone even use the second version, i.e `new Random(long seed)`?

Comment: I guess it would be used if you wanted the same set of randoms? Or if you wanted to provide your own distinct seed? I usually seed with `currentTimeMills()`

Comment: Are you asking what the difference is, or are you asking why anyone would use `new Random(long)`, given that you know the difference between it and `new Random()`?

Comment: You mean the reverse of C++? Like if you seed, you get the same random number set? Let me check.

Comment: @yshavit: Both, preferebly the latter. Why would anyone even use the second method?

Comment: @MattClark: You are spot on! So, it's the reverse of C++, eh

Answer (score 0):

When you set the seed you can predict (and reproduce) the output of the PRNG,

```
Random r = new Random(1L);
System.out.println(r.nextInt(100));
System.out.println(r.nextInt(100));
System.out.println(r.nextInt(100));
r = new Random(1L);
System.out.println(r.nextInt(100));
System.out.println(r.nextInt(100));
System.out.println(r.nextInt(100));
```

On my system that outputs

85, 88, 47

and then

85, 88, 47

because the seed was reset it *1*. Note that [`SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) has the behavior you describe.

Comment: Woah wait...I don't get it at all. Please explain. :(

Comment: If the first case, since the three numbers had the same seed, shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: The seed generates the sequence - not each individual number. Changing seeds will generate different sequences, and the same seed will generate the same sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`new Random()` creates a new `Random` instance, which is [very likely different](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random()), but not guaranteed to be, from any other instance of `Random` created.

`new Random(long seed)` creates a new `Random` instance, which will [initialize the random number generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random(long)) at that value, thus ensuring that two `Random` instances with the same seed will generate the same sequence.

Since `Random` is just a [pseudorandom number generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), it is ill-advised to use it for applications that require a truly random number generator.  However, for applications that don't require it, or for someone using a PRNG that they want to predict values around, it's not a terrible choice.

Comment: So, what would be suggested to have truly random functionality?

Comment: `SecureRandom` is a fine choice.